# Directory Search to array to populate Windows form datagrid

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a windows form via Powershell where users can search for the computers registered to a person, or search for a person's registered computers.  The registered user is stored in the `description` field, the computer names in the `name` field.  `$SearchIn` holds the value to search for, `$field` indicates the field to search in.

I can get the results I want via the console, but I'm attempting to push the results into a datagrid view on a windows form.  The datagrid in the script below is called `$dataGrid1`.  What I have below is an attempt to push the directory services search to an array, then set the datagrid datasource to an array.  I thought because the `$objectComputer` is an object rather than an array I had to create an array using `New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` and populate it using the `addrange` method set to the `$objComputer` object.

Ultimately what I get no matter what I'm trying is a blank datagrid view.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```html
Function Get-Info
{
    param($SearchIn,$Field)
    
    if ($field -eq "Name"){
        $filter="name=*$SearchIn*"
        }
    else
        {
        $filter="description=*$SearchIn*"
        }
    
    $strCategory = “computer”
    $objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
    $objSearcher.Filter = $filter 

    $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
    $objComputer=@()

    foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
        {
        $objComputer+=($objResult.Properties.item("Name"), $objResult.Properties.item("Description"))}
    $array=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
    $array=.addrange($objComputer)
    
    $dataGrid1.DataSource = $array
    $fComputerSearch.refresh() 
}#End Get-Info
```

Answer (score 0):

Uff your code is rather hard to read, next time please check the brackets {}

I think the end is incorrect:

```
$array=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
    $array=.addrange($objComputer)

    $dataGrid1.DataSource = $array
    $fComputerSearch.refresh()
```

I think it should be something like this:

```
# the fastest way to create empty ArrayList
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$list = @()
$list.AddRange($objComputer)

$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView -Property @{
    Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1024,768)
    ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
    DataSource = $list
}

$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)
$form.ShowDialog()
```